# A single page should be shorter

Tags: geometry

I need a single page (page 3 in my example) to be shorter than the rest of the pages. I don't know where the page break is (3 to 4), so I can't manually insert `\restoregeometry`. Therefore I've tried with the package (command) `afterpage`, but this has no visible effect.

Pages 1 to 3 are fine, pages 4 and later should look similar to first two pages.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry,blindtext,afterpage}
\geometry{textheight=183.5mm}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext[10]
  \newgeometry{textheight=50mm}
  \noindent This is a special (short) page

  \afterpage{\restoregeometry}
  \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

There is [this closed question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78278/how-to-set-page-geometry-for-a-single-page-only) which is very similar to mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all what you need is `\enlargethispage{value}`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry,blindtext}
\geometry{textheight=183.5mm}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext[10]

 \enlargethispage{-133.5mm} \noindent This is a special (short) page


  \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question, but I  now realize that my question does not reflect my problem.

Comment: @topskip edit your question, or ask new question.

Comment: New question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258072/text-after-footnote-text-but-within-the-text-area?lq=1