# Text after footnote text but within the text area

Tags: header-footer, geometry

I'd like to typeset text that appears within the typesetting area, but after the footnotes. (How) is this possible? I've tried to make the page shorter (with the geometry package and the `\newgeometry` command) and use the footer for that text. I am unable to reset the geometry on the next pages (see [my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258061/a-single-page-should-be-shorter)). But perhaps there is a better approach?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,blindtext}
\geometry{showframe}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[9]

\clearpage This is a special page\footnote{footnote}.

\specialcommand{A short horizontal rule and then in the next line: accumsan semper. Lorem ipsum dolor}

\blindtext[9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends a bit on the document and how "general" the solution should be. In your example a simple bottom float would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,blindtext}
\geometry{showframe}
\newcommand\specialcommand[1]{\begin{figure}[b]
\rule{3cm}{0.4pt}\\
#1
\end{figure}}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[9]

\clearpage This is a special page\footnote{footnote}.

\specialcommand{A short horizontal rule and then in the next line: accumsan semper. Lorem ipsum dolor}

\blindtext[9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And a suggestion with the `\enlargethispage` from your other question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,blindtext,eso-pic}
\geometry{showframe}

\newcommand\specialcommand[1]{%
 \enlargethispage{-1cm}
 \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
   \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{%
    \rule{3cm}{0.4pt}\par#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[9]

\clearpage This is a special page\footnote{footnote}.

\specialcommand{A short horizontal rule and then in the next line: accumsan semper. Lorem ipsum dolor}

\blindtext[9]
\end{document}
```