# Geometry for single page, redux

Tags: margins, page-breaking, geometry

I'm bummed that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78278/how-to-set-page-geometry-for-a-single-page-only) question is closed. I want to know how to do what the OP there wanted. So I'm asking again.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=2in}
\lipsum[1-7]
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

But lo, great sadness! What I wanted was that only the first page have the weird 2 inch top margin, and that, wherever that ends, we move on to other pages with 1.5 inch top margins.

So of course, we could try to throw a `vspace*{0.5in}` at the top. And look, there's nothing wrong with that hack, but it (a) doesn't actually do what I'm asking (the margins on the first page aren't actually any different; there's just a bit of extra space that makes it look like they are) and (b) doesn't work will with, e.g. the `letter` documentclass, since there's nowhere to put the `vspace*{0.5in}` command to get it to drop the date down. MWE for that:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{0.5in}

\begin{letter}{
Department of Stuff \\
California Institute of Things \\
Pasadena, CA 91125}

\opening{Hiya!}

\lipsum[1-7]
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

It (weirdly) just throws an extra blank page at the start of things. Nope, I *actually want* something that gives different margins for the first page and none of the following pages, but which allows paragraphs to break across the change.

Of course, someone might have a hack for the letter class too. And that's great! But shouldn't there be some nice uniform solution? I imagine there will be classes where neither the `\vspace*' nor the as-yet-to-be-determined-letter-class-hack work...

Comment: For a single page, you don't really need to change the margins, you can add or remove space as needed (overlay the margins).

Comment: Do you mean, as well, that the page has to break normally between pages 1 and 2 (e.g., mid-paragraph breaking)?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes! That's exactly right.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, yes. Of course. But suppose I'm using a funny class like letter or some such that adds all kinds of stuff (dates, addresses of the recipients, etc.) above where I start putting in the actual text of my document? I realize I could try an individual hack for each document class, but a nice uniform solution seems better.

Comment: The `\newgeometry` approach of my now deleted answer will not work in your case, because it causes a new page to start and does not carry over breakable text from a prior page.

Comment: In my opinion the `letter` class can be easily avoided. How about a solution that replicates your `letter` class behaviour *without* using `letter`?

Comment: @Werner Sure, that'd also be helpful (for me and I imagine for other folks as well), but I'm also curious: is the behavior I'm asking for (change margins, but do the normal things with paragraph breaks, etc.) just not achievable?

Comment: I suspect afterpage goes to great efforts not to change the margins in the middle of a paragraph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part of [Werner’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314960/69818) won’t work if the sender’s address is also specified (with the `\address` declaration).  In my opinion, it is more robust to patch the `\opening` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter} % To avoid confusion, let me explicitly declare 
                                % the paper size.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Unrelated to the question, but I like it.
\usepackage[
        margin=1.5in,
        showframe   % For this example only.
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\address{Revinu Jitis Drofnats\\
    Department of Farm Ecology\\
    University of St.~Anford\\
    Haga Alto, CA~94321}
\date{\today}

% The patch:
\pretocmd{\opening}{\vspace*{0.5in}}{}{}



\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{
Department of Stuff \\
California Institute of Things \\
Pasadena, CA 91125}

\opening{Hiya!}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Here’s the first page of the output:

[image: First page produced by the code]

Comment: It's just weird how `\opening` has to be patched in order to add space *before* the to and from address as well as the date. I know why, but it's just strange to specify document components in such an arbitrary way.

Comment: @Werner: The implementation of the `letter` class is very frugal.  Many years ago I tried my hand at writing a class for typesetting letters according to Italian style conventions (`texdoc cdpbundl`, in case you are curious), and I followed a modular approach, defining separate macros for the from and to address, the date, the (optional) subject, the salutation…

Comment: This seems like a fairly robust solution; I'll have a look at the documentation for`\pretocmd`. I imagine this will be helpful for doing something similar on other document classes that do funny things at the top.

Comment: @Shay: You’ll find `\pretocmd` in the documentation of the `etoolbox` package (just in case you didn’t know already ;-) .

Answer (score 4):

My assumption here is that you want to use some letter-head that is already on a piece of paper...

If you really want what you're after and *insist* on using the `letter` class, then you'll have to use a hack. To replicate your output *with* the top margin on the first page 0.5" bigger than the rest, add `\vspace*{0.5in}` as part of a new `\date` declaration... even though you could use `\today`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\date{\vspace*{0.5in}\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{
Department of Stuff \\
California Institute of Things \\
Pasadena, CA 91125}

\opening{Hiya!}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

---

You can easily recreate your current setup *without* using the `letter` class. The code also follows naturally from the output, making odd `letter`-specific constructions/macros superfluous.

Here is a similar output under `article`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,showframe]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{0.5in}

\mbox{}\hfill\today

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Department of Stuff \\
  California Institute of Things \\
  Pasadena, CA 91125
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Hiya!

\medskip

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\date{\vspace*{0.5in}\today}` trick is slick.

Answer (score 3):

The `flowfram` package has no problem changing margins between pages.  OTOH, it only defines the text area.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\newflowframe[1]{\textwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-0.5in}{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```