# Too much space in the bottom margin

Tags: margins

I wonder why Latex leaves this space in the bottom of the page and moves the last two lines of the paragraph to a new page. Here is a screenshot

[image]

even `\pagebreak` command fails to fix this probably.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the two line would remain on the previous page they would nearly touch the page number in the footer. There is clearly not enough space.

Comment: Look at the `geometry` package.  Do something like `\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}`

Comment: I cannot use such a command in the preamble of my thesis because this would make many changes to other pages. @JPi

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and specify more clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I want is to move these two lines in the previous page.

Comment: Try `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}`.

Comment: also this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78285/90297

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1670572/6154544

Comment: The geometry package allows you to change the margins in the middle of the document and back again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- if there is a prohibition against widow lines (`\widowpenalty=10000`), then `\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}` would probably be enough.