# How to get a bigger text area for a large image (or: reduced margins) on one page?

Tags: graphics, margins

In a document with the `scrreprt` class, I show an image with a caption.
The image is set to fill the text height.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=1\textheight]{example-image-a4}
\caption{Image caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would like this image to be bigger than that, but still on the page.
This is because the image shows an entire page of an old document which is originally in a larger format:
I want to show its geometry and typography, so the whole page has to be visible, but at the same time, it is important that some detail remains discernible.

For this, I have two options:

1. Increase the size of the image via the `height` or `width` option.
2. Increase the size of the text area (or: reduce the margins) on this page only.

Trying option 1, I increased the `height`, but already at `1.1\textheight`, the image shifts to the right and also covers the page number, while I expected it to be centered and located a bit further to the top of the page.

I don’t know how to achieve option 2:
the question »[How to set page geometry for a single page only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78278/how-to-set-page-geometry-for-a-single-page-only)« doesn’t have an up-to-date answer, and this task seems to be non-trivial.

---

How can I place an image on a whole page in such a way that it

- is a bit bigger than the text area of the rest of the document,
- stays within the printable area and leaves a *little* room for margins,
- does not cover the page number?

Comment: Maybe you could make use of the `\changepage{〈text height〉}{〈text width〉}{〈even-side margin〉}{〈odd-side margin〉}{〈column sep.〉}{〈topmargin〉}{〈headheight〉}{〈headsep〉}{〈footskip〉}` from the `changepage` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trim the graphic. Then some parts of it will be "outside" the frame:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
%red box for demo
\colorbox{red}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim=1cm 4cm 1cm 2cm]{example-image-a4}}
\caption{Image caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don’t understand the trim option here: I thought that it cuts parts of the image away. I will look into it tomorrow; gotta run for now!

Comment: I now understand the trim option better (I had never used it before). The use of xcolor is just for the red box? And geometry is loaded only to show the frame, while pass disables all the rest of the package? So, except for graphicx, I will not have to load any package.

Comment: Yes, apart from the trim the rest is only there to visualize the output.