# Three-column, full page index in tufte-book[twoside,symmetric]

Tags: makeindex, fullpage

I create two indexes in tufte-book.  I use the default settings for the first--*Index of artists*--which matches the body of the book, is two-column, and has the large margins used throughout the book.  (I'm running TeXShop 3.96 on a Mac.)

My problem centers on the other, general *Index*, which is so large I'd like to make it *three* columns *and run across the full page*.  I tried surrounding the `\makeindex` with `\begin{fullpage} ... \end{fullpage}` (see below).  That works on *half* the pages, but the margins are all wrong on the other half, interleaved, pages.  Basically, when encountering the `\begin{fullpage}` LaTeX "decides" whether the layout should assume everything following is on an *even* page or on an *odd* page, and adheres to that throughout the typesetting.

Here is the top few inches of the output pages...  First a "good" margin page of the Index:

[image: good Index page]

Next a "bad" margin page of the Index:

[image: bad Index page]

Here's a minimal working example of the source:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=artists,title=Index of artists,columns=2]

\makeindex[title=Index,columns=3]

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

Text here

\index[artists]{Picasso, Pablo}

\index{oil paint}

\printindex[artists]

\begin{fullwidth}
\printindex 
\end{fullwidth} 

\end{document}
```

**How do I ensure all the three-column Index pages are full page width and have proper margins?**

Comment: Try to clean the auxiliary files, and build the project with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the document class [`tufte-book`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex), a margin (of 2 inches) is reserved for sidenotes. Regarding options `twoside,symmetric`, the manual says:

> The `twoside` option will modify the running heads so that the
>   page number is printed on the outside edge (as opposed to always
>   printing the page number on the right-side edge in `oneside` mode).
>
> The `symmetric` option typesets the sidenotes on the outside edge of the
>   page. This is how books are traditionally printed, but is contrary to
>   Tufte’s book design which sets the sidenotes on the right side of the
>   page. This option implicitly sets the `twoside` option.

Therefore, using option `symmetric` (hence `twoside`) induces different values for the left margin  depending on the page number parity.

Using `oneside` option (and removing `symmetric`) yields the right hand side of the following screenshot (against `twoside,symmetric` on the left hand side).

[image]

On these screenshots, I've drawn a frame around the margins (using package `showframe`), to show that **the three columns already span over the full page width**. I also added other index entries to span over several columns:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{showframe}

\makeindex[name=artists,title={Index of artists},columns=3]

\makeindex[title=Index,columns=3]

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

Text here


\index[artists]{Picasso0, Pablo0}
\index[artists]{Picasso1, Pablo1}
\index[artists]{Picasso2, Pablo2}
\index[artists]{Picasso3, Pablo3}
\index[artists]{Picasso4, Pablo4}
\index[artists]{Picasso5, Pablo5}
\index[artists]{Picasso6, Pablo6}
\index[artists]{Picasso7, Pablo7}
\index[artists]{Picasso8, Pablo8}
\index[artists]{Picasso9, Pablo9}
\index[artists]{Picasso10, Pablo10}
\index[artists]{Picasso11, Pablo11}
\index[artists]{Picasso12, Pablo12}
\index[artists]{Picasso13, Pablo13}
\index[artists]{Picasso14, Pablo14}
\index[artists]{Picasso15, Pablo15}
\index[artists]{Picasso16, Pablo16}
\index[artists]{Picasso17, Pablo17}
\index[artists]{Picasso18, Pablo18}
\index[artists]{Picasso19, Pablo19}
\index[artists]{Picasso20, Pablo20}
\index[artists]{Picasso21, Pablo21}
\index[artists]{Picasso22, Pablo22}
\index[artists]{Picasso23, Pablo23}
\index[artists]{Picasso24, Pablo24}
\index[artists]{Picasso25, Pablo25}
\index[artists]{Picasso26, Pablo26}
\index[artists]{Picasso27, Pablo27}
\index[artists]{Picasso28, Pablo28}
\index[artists]{Picasso29, Pablo29}
\index[artists]{Picasso30, Pablo30}
\index[artists]{Picasso31, Pablo31}
\index[artists]{Picasso32, Pablo32}
\index[artists]{Picasso33, Pablo33}
\index[artists]{Picasso34, Pablo34}
\index[artists]{Picasso35, Pablo35}
\index[artists]{Picasso36, Pablo36}
\index[artists]{Picasso37, Pablo37}
\index[artists]{Picasso38, Pablo38}
\index[artists]{Picasso39, Pablo39}
\index[artists]{Picasso40, Pablo40}
\index[artists]{Picasso41, Pablo41}
\index[artists]{Picasso42, Pablo42}
\index[artists]{Picasso43, Pablo43}
\index[artists]{Picasso44, Pablo44}
\index[artists]{Picasso45, Pablo45}
\index[artists]{Picasso46, Pablo46}
\index[artists]{Picasso47, Pablo47}
\index[artists]{Picasso48, Pablo48}
\index[artists]{Picasso49, Pablo49}
\index[artists]{Picasso50, Pablo50}
\index[artists]{Picasso51, Pablo51}
\index[artists]{Picasso52, Pablo52}
\index[artists]{Picasso53, Pablo53}
\index[artists]{Picasso54, Pablo54}
\index[artists]{Picasso55, Pablo55}
\index[artists]{Picasso56, Pablo56}
\index[artists]{Picasso57, Pablo57}
\index[artists]{Picasso58, Pablo58}
\index[artists]{Picasso59, Pablo59}
\index[artists]{Picasso60, Pablo60}
\index[artists]{Picasso61, Pablo61}
\index[artists]{Picasso62, Pablo62}
\index[artists]{Picasso63, Pablo63}
\index[artists]{Picasso64, Pablo64}
\index[artists]{Picasso65, Pablo65}
\index[artists]{Picasso66, Pablo66}
\index[artists]{Picasso67, Pablo67}
\index[artists]{Picasso68, Pablo68}
\index[artists]{Picasso69, Pablo69}
\index[artists]{Picasso70, Pablo70}
\index[artists]{Picasso71, Pablo71}
\index[artists]{Picasso72, Pablo72}
\index[artists]{Picasso73, Pablo73}
\index[artists]{Picasso74, Pablo74}
\index[artists]{Picasso75, Pablo75}
\index[artists]{Picasso76, Pablo76}
\index[artists]{Picasso77, Pablo77}
\index[artists]{Picasso78, Pablo78}
\index[artists]{Picasso79, Pablo79}
\index[artists]{Picasso80, Pablo80}
\index[artists]{Picasso81, Pablo81}
\index[artists]{Picasso82, Pablo82}
\index[artists]{Picasso83, Pablo83}
\index[artists]{Picasso84, Pablo84}
\index[artists]{Picasso85, Pablo85}
\index[artists]{Picasso86, Pablo86}
\index[artists]{Picasso87, Pablo87}
\index[artists]{Picasso88, Pablo88}
\index[artists]{Picasso89, Pablo89}
\index[artists]{Picasso90, Pablo90}
\index[artists]{Picasso91, Pablo91}
\index[artists]{Picasso92, Pablo92}
\index[artists]{Picasso93, Pablo93}
\index[artists]{Picasso94, Pablo94}
\index[artists]{Picasso95, Pablo95}
\index[artists]{Picasso96, Pablo96}
\index[artists]{Picasso97, Pablo97}
\index[artists]{Picasso98, Pablo98}
\index[artists]{Picasso99, Pablo99}



\index{oil paint}

\printindex[artists]

\begin{fullwidth}
\printindex 
\end{fullwidth} 

\end{document}
```

If you absolutely want a `twoside,symmetric` document, use `\thispagestyle` command with package `geometry`.

**EDIT** Here are the complete details using the [`geometry`](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and [`afterpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) packages, thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78285). Thanks also to [@mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514936/116691) for using `tikz` to shorten the TeX code.

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{showframe,tikz}

\usepackage{geometry,afterpage}

\makeindex[name=artists,title={Index of artists},columns=3]

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

Text here

\foreach \s in {1,2,...,200}{
\index[artists]{Picasso\s, Pablo\s}}

\afterpage{%
\newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in}
\printindex[artists]
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
} 

\end{document}
```

**Produces** the following (left hand side: pages 1 & 2, right hand side: pages 3 & 4). The style for the rest of the book (margins especially) remains unchanged thanks to the `\restoregeometry` command.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.  But as far as I can see your three columns span just the *central* text region, not as my example showed the *full page* width.  (See my top image... which is what I want throughout.)  If you can show the full code using geometry and such that works, I'll accept the answer.  I've tried and nothing quite works perfectly.  (Also, I want to retain the original style throughout the rest of the book, so I won't change the full book to oneside, etc.)

Comment: I've edited the answer according to your feedback. Does that work for you? Is this what you wanted?

Comment: jcdh:  Oh so very close...  I get the three columns across all full pages (thanks!) but for some reason (unlike your perfect example) my entries do not extend as low on the page as the rest of the body of the book.  (Note:  I did't use showframe and tikz, as it seems those were just for displaying your solution.)  Is there some \textheight or other change I need?

Comment: jcdh:  I just needed to adjust \textheight and now all works beautifully.  Thanks so VERY much (accept).  (Buy my book when it comes out and see your handywork!)

Comment: Ahahah, glad if it works! `tikz` and `showframes` were indeed for the example.

Answer (score 2):

Based on jdhd's answer, here is an attempt by using `adjmulticol` for the fullwidth environment and `tikz` for its `\foreach` command. Although this work it causes another problem: The Index list doesn't change page. Maybe someone can work on that. Nevertheless I present this solution:

```
\documentclass[oneside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{showframe,adjmulticol,tikz}

\makeindex[name=artists,title={Index of artists},columns=3]

\makeindex[title=Index,columns=3]


\newcommand{\full}[1]{\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}
#1
\end{adjmulticols}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

Text here

\foreach \s in {1,2,...,200}{
\index[artists]{Picasso\s, Pablo\s}}



\index{oil paint}

\printindex[artists]

\begin{fullwidth}
\printindex 
\end{fullwidth} 


\full{\printindex[artists]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  A helpful ingredient, and perhaps someone can figure out how to fix the remaining problem(s).  Note, though, that I don't want to change the rest of the book... which has been carefully designed.

Comment: Of course. That would be tricky. I think I added as few as possible to your MWE. Also I tried a lot to find a way to fix this issue with the page. I use this command in my work for a fullwidth environment in a document like yours and it works with plain text. As it turned out it doesn't work with `index`.