# Use full page for an image only in a single page

Tags: circuitikz, fullpage

I have created a circuit schematic in circuitikz that is quite large and I want to use the entire page for that. How can I set that only on that page there are no margins? I know that in order to set 0 margins in the entire document you should use `\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}` but this will set for all the pages in the document. Is it possible to set it only on one page?

Comment: Does this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78278/how-to-set-page-geometry-for-a-single-page-only) helps you?

Comment: Or you can use `overlay` to hide the size of the picture and put it in one `figure[p]` environment maybe with a bit of `vspace` and `hspace`.  ... like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth

Comment: you don't need to change the margins, just run in to them, eg `\centering\makebox[0pt]{... your circuit...}`  will allow it to be arbtrarily wide with no warnings given